# condition for the uniqueness of the input data

Tags: python, django

I need names and surnames of the employees to not match. and so that an error occurs after trying to save changes if the same person is specified 2 times. What's wrong?

```py
class JrtnPerson(models.Model):
    rtn = models.ForeignKey(Drtn, verbose_name='Подразделение Ростехнадзора', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Имя и Отчество')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    tel_mob = PhoneNumberField(verbose_name="Номер телефона мобильный", blank=True, null=True)
    tel_rab = PhoneNumberField(verbose_name="Номер телефона рабочий", blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Электронная почта", blank=True, null=True)
    # def __str__(self):
    #     return '%s %s' % (self.surname, self.name)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.JrtnPerson.objects.filter(surname=self.surname, name=self.name).exists():
            super(surname,name,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```py
class JrtnPersonPersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ( 'name', 'surname','rtn',)
    search_fields = ('rtn__name_short', 'rtn__name_full', 'name', 'surname', 'tel_mob', 'tel_rab', 'email')

    class Meta:
        model = JrtnPerson
```

```py
 class JrtnCuratorInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = JrtnCurator
    # fields = ('person', 'rol')
    # search_fields=['curator',]
    autocomplete_fields = ('curator',)
    # classes = ('grp-collapse grp-open',)
    # inline_classes = ('grp-collapse grp-open',)
    formfield_overrides = {
        ForeignKey: {'empty_label': 'Выберите...'},
    }

    def get_extra(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        return 0 if obj and obj.jrtncurator_set.exists() else 1

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        field = super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == 'curator':
            field.widget.attrs['style'] = 'width: 300px;'
        return field
```

Comment: There is no error, and moreover, updates will introduce problems.

Comment: but i still can add 2 same person, and that's wrong. i want to make it impossible

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the save method is incorrectly implemented. You should utilize Django model features and use model-level validation or constraints to ensure data uniqueness.

Your current implementation of the `save` method in your model is incorrect. You need to call `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` without the field names.

You can use the `unique_together` option in the model's `Meta` class.

Here is an updated version of your code as per your need.

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

class JrtnPerson(models.Model):
    rtn = models.ForeignKey(Drtn, verbose_name='Подразделение Ростехнадзора', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Имя и Отчество')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    tel_mob = PhoneNumberField(verbose_name="Номер телефона мобильный", blank=True, null=True)
    tel_rab = PhoneNumberField(verbose_name="Номер телефона рабочий", blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Электронная почта", blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'surname')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Validate before saving (optional but recommended)
        self.full_clean()
        super(JrtnPerson, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    # Optional: String representation of the object
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.surname} {self.name}'
```

Here, `unique_together` constraint ensures that no two JrtnPerson instances can have the same combination of name & surname.
In the `save()` methods the `full_clean` method is called before saving to validate the model instance, including the unique_together constraint.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I formulated the problem a little incorrectly. I already have a database with employees and I don’t need to add anything new to it. But when I create an order, I assign several employees to it, and they should not be repeated. Can you please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Please provide more details on how you setup your Order class and employees.

Comment: please add these into your main question for better formatting.

Comment: i've done, but not everything fited

Comment: probably there should be
 def validate_unique(self, exclude=None):
        return super(JrtnPerson, self).validate_unique(exclude)